# ng-click gives "href undefined " error on a function call with a parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

After seeing multiple issues around this, I'm still unable to figure out why the error occurred.

Here is my code so far:

**app.js**

```
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.redirectto = function (id) {
        if(id === 'test') {
            $window.location.href = "http://mydomain.test.com/";      
        }
    };
};
```

**html file:**

```
<div layout="column" flex=40 layout-align="center center"
     ng-click="redirectto('test')" role="button"><span>Test</span>
</div>
```

There is no much complication am looking here.But when I amusing grunt to build the source, I am getting the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined

Comment: try `window.location.href`

Comment: use `$location`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`$location.path`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location):

```
$location.path('http://mydomain.test.com/');
```

---

In your full code, it will be:

```
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.redirectto = function (id) {
        if(id === 'test') {
            $location.path('http://mydomain.test.com/');
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: `$location.path(url)` is *the Angular way* for redirection. From [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location): "Change path when called with parameter and return $location."